# How do I set a PHP variable from within a PHP class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Connect to a MySQL database using a class (Sorted)
2. Query a MySQL table (Sorted)
3. Set a PHP global PHP variable that can be referenced throughout the website (Not Sorted)

***Database connection class***

```
<?php

class dbh
{

    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;

    protected function connect()
    {

        $this->servername ="localhost";
        $this->username ="neo";
        $this->password ="p.MR~11^";
        $this->dbname ="neo_db";

        $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);

        return $conn;

    }

}

?>
```

This is my dbh.inc.php file and it works fine and produces zero errors.

***SQL SELECT class***

```
<?php

class modules extends dbh
{

    protected function getallmodules()
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM modules";
        $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;

        if($numRows > 0)
        {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {

                $data[] = $row;

            }

            return $data;

        }

    }

}

?>
```

This is my modules.inc.php file and it works fine and produces zero errors.

***SQL view modules class***

```
<?php

class viewmodules extends modules
{

    public $widgets;

    public function showallmodules()
    {

        $modules = $this->getallmodules();
        
        foreach($modules as $module)
        {

            $this->module['widgets'];

        }

    }

}

?>
```

This is my viewmodules.inc.php file. I need to set a global variable called $widgets.

***PHP output page***

```
<?php

    $modules = new viewmodules();
    $modules->showallmodules();

    if($modules->widgets):

    //some code here

    endif;

?>
```

Comment: _"I need to set a global variable called $widgets."_ - why? If you've instantiated your `viewmodules()` class you can retrieve the data from there whenever you need it. Global variables aren't a great idea anyway. How will using one help you?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its retrieving the data that's the issue. I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: What is the purpose of `dbh` class? It seems utterly useless. Why not just get rid of it?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do or what the problem is. Which piece of code do you think is not working correctly? What is that "global" variable meant to do? Why do you even require a global variable if you are working on OOP?

Comment: `getallmodules()` should contain only a single line of code. Why do you overcomplicate it so much? `return $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM modules")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` Also, you really should not connect anew each time. Open the connection once and reuse it.

Comment: Aplogies, I did state at the beginning of this that I'm new to OOP.

Comment: It's ok to be new, but this information isn't needed on Stack Overflow. This is not a tutoring site. If you want to share a question with the world, it needs to be reasonably scoped and clear enough to receive good answers. If you are not sure yourself what code you are writing, then it might mean that you have do to some research on your own prior to asking a question on SO.

Comment: Message received, thank you for your help. I'll look to review my post in order to obtain the required assistance.